# Xamarin Forms Webview stopped working - UWP App

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

I've a uwp app that requires login at start up through an url, for which I've been using Webview control. It has been doing ok until recently but suddenly stopped working without changing anything related to the login sequence. I've been using VS Community 2022 but the app was built in VS Community 2019, .NET Standard 2, Prism 7.2

Here's my xaml:

```
    <ScrollView>
        <WebView x:Name="webView"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Source="{Binding LoginURL}"/>
    </ScrollView>
```

Code in the view model (extracted relevant portions):

```
    private string _loginURL;
    public string LoginURL         
    {
        get => _loginURL;
        set => SetProperty(ref _loginURL, value);
    }

    private string _redirectURL;
    public string RedirectURL
    {
        get => _redirectURL;
        set => SetProperty(ref _redirectURL, value);
    }

    private void StartLogin(bool userInitialized)
    {
        try
        {
            if (userInitialized)
            {
                RedirectURL = _loginService.RedirectURL;
                LoginURL = _loginService.LoginURL;

                Debug.WriteLine("RedirectURL: " + RedirectURL);
                Debug.WriteLine("LoginURL: " + LoginURL);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logService.LogError(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

The code behind the user control with webview:

```
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        webView.Navigating += CatchRedirectURL;
    }

    private async void CatchRedirectURL(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("e.Url: " + e.Url);
        Debug.WriteLine("webView.Source: " + (webView.Source as UrlWebViewSource).Url);

        var vm = BindingContext as LoginViewModel;
        if (e.Url.Contains(vm.RedirectURL))
        {
            var webViewSender = (WebView)sender;
            e.Cancel = true; // prevent further browsing

            var requestToken = ExtractRequestToken(e.Url);
            var user = await vm.GenerateSessionAsync(requestToken);

            var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();

            if (user.AccessToken == null)
            {
                string msg = "Login Unsuccessful";
                htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
                                  <h1 style=""text-align:center;"">" + msg + @"</h1>
                                  <p style=""text-align:center;"">oops...something went wrong.</p>
                                  </body>
                                </html>";
            }
            else
            {
                string msg = "Hello, " + user.UserShortName + "!";
                htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
                                  <h1 style=""text-align:center;"">" + msg + @"</h1>
                                  <p style=""text-align:center;"">Welcome</p>
                                  </body>
                                </html>";
            }
            webViewSender.Source = htmlSource;
        }
    }
```

Immediately after loading the control, the StartLogin method is called from the view model. The debug output is here:

[image]

All the above urls are valid and if I copy and paste them in a browser, they work fine. But in the app the webview control is just plain blank despite the source property populated with correct url. I'm totally clueless as to what's going wrong here, especially when it was working so beautifully a few days ago.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I confirm if the target url has an invalid certificate? Also, there's a [similar thread] (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4811) with blank page which is caused by invalid cert(self-signed). If possible, could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Comment: The target url works just fine when accessed with a browser such as chrome and has a valid certificate. This is a UWP app.

Comment: Are you creating a `Universal Windows` app using VS Community 2022? What if you directly set the source for the `Webviewi in xamal and see if it can open the page? Last but not least,could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating a Universal Windows app using VS Community 2022. No, it doesn't work even if I set the source directly. A simple url like "https://www.google.co.in" is working, but not the one I want to use which has query parameters. More baffling is the fact that the entire setup worked like a charm a little while ago and I didn't change a thing there. I'm thinking it's a simple bug that's introduced with the recent MAUI update (my solution was created long before) and would like to roll back any updates if indeed its a bug. Please fix it ASAP.

Comment: I would suggest you can roll back your `VS` to the previous working version. It could be a potential issue.

Comment: There's no simple way to "roll back" to a previous version of VS Community. Any updates must be able to be rolled back, just in case they break something working alright. Ain't that simple?

Comment: With [Visual Studio Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#step-3---install-the-visual-studio-installer), you can install multiple versions of VS and don't need to roll back.